# Storing butter for longer than a month

Tags: butter

I have had unsalted butter in the fridge for a while and used it from time to time. Now I realize that's it's been there for many, many months. It tastes fine but is it safe to keep it longer than a month?

Comment: http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/16649

Comment: Thank you. I just wondered if they are overcautious because it tastes fine and I was eating it till recently.

Comment: I think they are overly cautious, yes, since they would want to err on the side of caution. Personally, if the butter looks and tastes okay then I would eat it without hesitation almost no matter how long it had been in the fridge.

Answer (score 1):

Oxidation can make the fat in the butter rancid.  You would taste and smell that, so it's probably safe.  Refrigeration and darkness slow the process of oxidation.

I freeze butter and take it out of the freezer a stick at a time.  Butter appears to last approximately forever if frozen.

Comment: I've not seen butter sticks at supermarkets in the UK like they do in the US.